# C# proper foreach syntax to iterate over List

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I've been trying to use `foreach` to iterate over a `List` of objects and just can't seem to get the correct syntax. Here is a simplified example.

```
    class foo
    {
        private int x = 1;
        public foo(int y)
        {
            x = y;
        }

        public int X
        {
            get { return x; }
        }
    }

    class bar
    {
        foo footest = new foo(3);
        private List<foo> myfoo = new List<foo>();
        public bar()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {

                myfoo.Add(footest);
            }
        }
    /*Below is what I can't seem to get working. I want to write a method 
    that iterates through the list of foo objects and displays a property for
    each one. The compiler gives an error under foreach that says "A get or
 set accessor expected."
        /*public void getall
    {
        foreach (bar Myfoo in myfoo) //error under foreach
    {
        Console.Write(Myfoo.X);
    }*/
}
```

Comment: `foreach(var Myfoo in myfoo)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are attempting to create a Property you will need to use the proper syntax, that is what the error is telling you. If you are just wanting to create a method you will need to put the parenthesis at the end of the declaration. Try this instead

```
public void getall()
{

    foreach (foo Myfoo in myfoo) //error under foreach
    {
        Console.Write(Myfoo.X);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The *compiler error reported* is due to to **missing parenthesis** and is thus an invalid (or, not parsed as) a method declaration.

```
public void getall () // every method declaration must have parenthesis
{
    foreach (bar Myfoo in myfoo) {
       Console.Write(Myfoo.X);
    }
}
```

(There are also other issues such as ".. does not contain a definition for 'X'".)

Comment: `myFoo` is a `List` of type `foo` not `bar`.  This would throw an error.

Comment: @Ballbin That is correct. I am only providing a correction for the *reported* issue; questions are one-shot. (And hopefully the OP should continue his/her own troubleshooting after resolving this parse error.)

Answer (score 0):

`myFoo` is a list of `foo` so you would loop through it grabbing the `foo` objects from the list.  Try: `foreach(foo fooItem in myFoo){...}`

Comment: This does not explain: The compiler gives an error under foreach that says "A get or
 set accessor expected."

Answer (score 0):

As well as the answers above regarding parenthesis, you will also need to note the following.

Try something like this in the method to resolve the next errors:

```
foreach (var f in myfoo)
{
    // do something with the 'f' here
}
```

or

```
foreach (foo f in myfoo)
{
    // do something with the 'f' here
}
```

In the code you posted, you tried to use an incorrect type to iterate with. `myfoo` is of type `List<foo>`, so contains a list of `foo` objects. When you loop over this list, you need to use the same type of object in the list, so in this case, a `foo` object.

Comment: He OP has the class `bar` (terrible name). In any case, the error reported is not a Type Error or runtime exception (maybe it's incorrectly reported, but make a case).